# how to create hover effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have three images I want to show some text on one particular image when my cursor goes on that image like on first image text should come from top, second image text should come from left and on third image text should come from right This hover effect already done in css but I have do it in Javascript so please help me with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you put your html maybe, or explain what are your problems making it?

Comment: Either provide some code or some generated link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
     let p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
      let div = document.querySelector("div");
      div.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandler);
      div.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveHandler);
      function mouseOverHandler(e) {
        //top
        p[0].style.top = 0;
        //left
        p[1].style.left = 0;
        //right
        p[2].style.right = 0;
      }
      function mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
        //top
        p[0].style.top = "-75px";
        //left
        p[1].style.left = "-75px";
        //right
        p[2].style.right = "-75px";
      }
```

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: pink;
        position: relative;
        left: 300px;
        top: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      p {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:50px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }
      p:nth-child(1) {
        top: -50px;
        left: 75px;
      }
      p:nth-child(2) {
        top: 75px;
        left: -50px;
      }
      p:nth-child(3) {
        top: 75px;
        right: -50px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>top</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>right</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**How about this**

Comment: You are a good student, teacher makes a question and you give the solution.

Comment: I only started learning JS two months ago，that's all I can think of :)